# Avoid display of text in CMD

Tags: c++, cmd

I am using a command in c++:

```
system(echo yes|cacls cred.txt /P everyone:n);
```

To make file unreadable and undeleteable but when this command runs ,it shows the path of that file and the file name but I don't want this to be shown
This actually belongs to Batch Scripting but i am using C++

Comment: Learn how to use `CreateProcess` to create a hidden window.

Comment: But i don't want to hide all window ,just that text